# bootstrap issue: image overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here's my markup:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/foo.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 vorteil">
                 text
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<! -- plus 3 more items -->
</div>
```

which will look like this:
[image]

the problem however is - when reducing the browser width it will turn out like this:

[image]

the image will overflow its container although it should be responsive .. 
any ideas what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping the divs in a link...that's likely to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the red and grey divs in a DIV tag, not a link. Give the following style to your containing div:

```
.containing-div {display:block; overflow:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the parent class `.container` form bootstrap. look at [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px grey solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="///dummyimage.com/300x600">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 vorteil">
            text
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <! -- plus 3 more items -->
  </div>
</div>
```